# How to pair elements of a nestlist?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a this list for example
`expdata={{49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54},{0,3,5,2,0,1}}`
and I want to rearrange it like this
`expdata={{49,0},{50,3},{51,5},{52,2},{53,0},{54,1}}`.

Comment: This again? Maybe we should get an elementary list operation stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

### Example

**Code**

```
Transpose @ expdata
```

**Note:** `expdata` as in your OP prior to any rearrangement

**Output**

> {{49, 0}, {50, 3}, {51, 5}, {52, 2}, {53, 0}, {54, 1}}

**Reference**

[Transpose](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)